# php object name from var

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

i get object from json like this

```
{"valid":"yes","date":"2017-01-04","data-val":{"current":25}}
```

i want to get current value
i create a var include name current

```
$johndoe = 'current';
```

but i fail to call it like this :

```
$currentjohn = $data['data-val'][$johndoe];
```

fail

```
$currentjohn = $data['data-val']['.$johndoe.'];
```

also fail

```
$currentjohn = $data['data-val']->$johndoe;
```

fail too

how to do it right way
or
how to get 'current' if i didn't know that key name is current

thank you for helping

Comment: have you decode **json_decode($json)** ??

Comment: @krunal : yes sir i decode it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an object the syntax is:

```
$data->{'data-val'}->$johndoe;
```

(the curly braces need to be used because of the hyphen in the name. This is an object, not an array.)

Demo: https://eval.in/709782

as an array:

```
$data['data-val'][$johndoe];
```

Demo: https://eval.in/709784

A variable in single quotes will not be a variable and you can't concatenate in quotes. So:

```
$currentjohn = $data['data-val']['.$johndoe.'];
```

had a couple issues.